# Should CSRF tokens be server-side validated?

Tags: django, security, csrf

First, I want to make sure I got the CSRF token workflow right.
The server sets a cookie on my machine, on the site's domain. The browser prevents access to this cookie from other domains. When a POST request is made, I send the CSRF token to the server that then compares it to my cookie. It they're not the same, a 403 Forbidden page is returned.

Now, if I manually change the value of the token in the cookie and send that new value in the POST request, should the server return a 403 or not? Does the server need to validate the token agains a value stored on the server or on the cookie?

I am using the default implementation of CSRF protection on Django 1.3 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/) and it validates the token sent in the request against the token only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you send the token?

Usually, the tokens should be some function (with a secret key - known only to the server; e.g., MAC) of the cookie! not the cookie.

Than the flow is as follows:
1. Client sends the server request with a cookie.
2. Server returns a web page with CSRF token(s) for different purposes (e.g., forms or just a simple get requests via the URL).
3. The client performs some action (via POST or GET) and sends request with the token (in the request body or in the URL) and with the cookie.
4. The server is stateless, but it can verify that the request was sent by the same client by calculating the function (with the secret key that the server knows) on the cookie (or on part of it), and comparing the output with the token.

In the case of CSRF, the cookie is automatically appended to the request by the browser, but the attacker (that probably even doesn't know the cookie) cannot add the corresponding tokens.

I believe you should do something like this.

> Now, if I manually change the value of the token in the cookie and
>   send that new value in the POST request, should the server return a
>   403 or not? Does the server need to validate the token agains a value
>   stored on the server or on the cookie?

The server should be stateless (usually). You don't want to verify the token every request against some value in a database or something like that. It is better to verify against the cookie.
In that case, if you change the token, than it probably won't match the cookie, and you should send 403.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Yes, either you, or the framework you are using, needs to have server-side logic to validate a CSRF token. It cannot be a cookie, it has to be something that requires the user to be on your page, versus click on a link an attacker provides.

---

You've got the workflow pretty much correct. The first step is to generate a cryptographically random string that cannot be predicted by an attacker. Every programming language has its own construct to do this, but a 24 - 32 character string should be good to serve the purpose.

Before we get to the next step, let's make sure we know what threat we're dealing with - we don't want an attacker to make a request on behalf of the user, so there should be something that is accessible to the browser that requires the user to perform an action to send the token, BUT, if the user clicks on something the attacker has set up, the token should not be sent.

Given this, the one way this should NOT be done is using cookies. The browser will automatically send cookies every single time a request is made to the domain the cookie is set on, so this automatically defeats our defense.

That said, let's go to the next step, which is to set this token in a way that is verifiable by you on the server side, but not accessible to the attacker. There's multiple ways to do this:

1) **A CSRF Header**: This is done in many node.js/Express installations - the CSRF token is sent as a header, to be specific, a X-CSRF-Token header. After generating this token, the server stores this in the session store for that particular cookie. On the front end, the token is stored as a JavaScript variable, which means only requests generated on that particular page can have the header.. Whenever a request is made, both the session cookie (in the case of node.js, connect.sid) and the X-CSRF-Token is required for all POST/PUT/DELETE requests. If the wrong token is sent, the server sends a 401 Unauthorized, and regenerates the token, requesting login from the user.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.NODE_ENV = {};
window.NODE_ENV.csrf = "q8t4gLkMFSxFupWO7vqkXXqD";
window.NODE_ENV.isDevelopment = "true";
</script>
```

2) **A Hidden Form Value**: A lot of PHP installations use this as the CSRF defense mechanism. Depending on the configuration, either a session specific or a request specific (latter is overkill unless the application needs it) token is embedded in a hidden form field. This way, it is sent every time a form is submitted. The method of verification varies - it can be via verifying it against the database, or it can be a server-specific session store.

3) **[Double Submit Cookies](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Double_Submit_Cookies)**: This is a mechanism suggested by OWASP, where in addition to sending the session cookies via the header, you also include it in the forms submitted. This way, once you verify that the session is valid, you can verify that the form contains the session variables also. If you use this mechanism, it is critical to make sure that you validate the user's session before validating CSRF; otherwise, it introduces flaws.

While building/testing this mechanism, it is important to note that while a lot of implementations limit it to POST/DELETE/PUT transactions, this is because it is automatically assumed that all sensitive transactions happen through this verbs. If your application performs sensitive transactions (such as activations) using GET, then you need this mechanism for GET/HEAD also.